# Reduction from recursive language to recursive enumerable

Tags: turing-machines, computability, reductions, polynomial-time, enumeration

If any  language
$L_1$ reduces  $L_2$ in polynomial time $L_1\leq_p^\mathsf{}L_2.$ If $L_1$ is recursive then $L_2$ is recursive and recursively enumerable, is it true? Because $L_2$ is at least as hard as $L_1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. However, its true that $L_2$ is at least as hard as $L_1$. The opposite isn't true: take for example $L_2$ being the halting problem, and $L_1=\emptyset$.

Comment: sahar Please explain little bit... I am very much begginer

Comment: The halting problem isn't decidable, whilst $L_1=\emptyset$ is trivially decidable (reject every input). Try to show a reduction **from** $\emptyset$ (which will be $L_1$ in your question) **to** the halting problem (which will be $L_2$ in your question). This will be a counter-example to what you are asking

Comment: $L_2$ is  undecidable, so how $L_1$ is reduces to $L_2$? It isn't understable....

Comment: Follow the definiton of what a reduction is.

Comment: could you explain in one line?

Comment: A reduction is a *computable* function $f:\Sigma^*\rightarrow \Sigma^*$ such that $x\in L_1\iff f(x)\in L_2$

Comment: here $\phi$ ∈ $L_1$ understand but what is $f(x)$ here? $f(x)$ is turning machine is halt at $x=\phi$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-one_reduction#Formal_languages

Comment: "This says that with regards to many-one reducibility, the halting problem is the most complicated of all recursively enumerable problems. " So how $L_1$ reduces to $L_2$ is right, I don't see any contradiction.. Please elaborate your answer where contradiction is occurring..

Comment: Please try to follow the definition provided in the link and construct by yourself the reduction.

Comment: I understand all things.. But where contradiction is occurring.. Everything seems to be fine

Comment: The contradiction is that $L_2$ is not decidable, while $L_1$ is.

Comment: $L_1\leq_p^\mathsf{}L_2.$   If $L_2$ is RE then $L_1$  is recursive, is it true?

Comment: $L_1$ will also be RE (recursively enumerable)

Comment: If $L_1$ is $RE$ then it is Semi-decidable. So how Semi-decidable reduces to undecidable halting problem?